# Google map and location is showing null at the time of adding marker when i use GoogleApiClient to find location

Tags: android

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

TextView tvLocation;
Location lastLocation;

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
GoogleMap map ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLocation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLoc);

    map=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    lastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(lastLocation!=null){
        tvLocation.setText(String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude())+String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
        Log.d("location:",lastLocation.toString());

        updateUI(lastLocation);
        }
}

private void updateUI(Location lastLocation) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),lastLocation.getLongitude())).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.icon)));
    map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),lastLocation.getLongitude()))
    .radius(10).fillColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800).strokeColor(R.color.abc_secondary_text_material_dark));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) MainActivity.this);

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
}
```

It is rendering the google map properly but when i am trying to add marker at the last location/current location it shows null pointer exception at line 62 and 67. More specifically

```
  updateUI(lastLocation)

  map.addMarker(....)
```

Anybody can help me please to resolve this issue. Thanks advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the *map* object is not null? maybe it's not yet created when you call updateUI() from onConnected().

Comment: Yes, I got that point. What should i do to resolve it.

Comment: Give a solution by editing my code if you can please. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way i figured it out..

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity      implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

TextView tvLocation;
Location lastLocation;

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
GoogleMap map ;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoc);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}




@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

   // lastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
  // if(lastLocation!=null){
    //    tvLocation.setText(String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude())+String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
    //    Log.d("location:",lastLocation.toString());
        updateUI();

        }


private void updateUI() {

    LatLng location=new LatLng(getLocation().getLatitude(),getLocation().getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("You are here"));

}

private Location getLocation() {
    Location currentLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    return currentLocation;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) MainActivity.this);

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it should work:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tvLocation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLoc);

            map=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
         if(map!= null){
             addTheMarker();
         } else {
             handler = new Handler();

             final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                   addTheMarker();
                   handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                 }
              };
             handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
         }
     }

   private void addTheMarker(){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),lastLocation.getLongitude())).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.icon)));
        map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),lastLocation.getLongitude()))
            .radius(10).fillColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_800).strokeColor(R.color.abc_secondary_text_material_dark));
   }
```